# Notificaciones con push.js y php

Tags: php, push.js

Estoy tratando de implementar notificaciones en mi pagina, en [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) funciona correctamente, pero en [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) me sale este error

aquí mi código

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/push.js"></script>
</head>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="notificacion">Ver</button>

<script>
 $("#notificacion").click(function(){
     Push.create("hola");
 });
 </script>
```

y este es el error que aparece en chrome

> Uncaught (in promise) PushError: permission request declined

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: revisa esto: https://github.com/Nickersoft/push.js/issues/119

Comment: Si estas ejecutando tu página desde un servidor, verifica que tenga certificado SSL ya que Chrome no permite notificaciones de páginas que no cuenten con el.

Comment: ¿Pediste permiso para mostrar notificaciones?